# Shuffle parts of a QList

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qlist

i have a list and i want to make 3 different shuffles in this list like this:

- 1º shuffle: the first ten items;
- 2º shuffle: from the 11th item to the 20th;
- 3º shuffle: from the 21st item to the end

this is what i did so far:

```
QList<QString> list;

list << "a" << "b" << ...

    std::random_shuffle(list.begin(), list.begin()+10);
    list.takeFirst();
    QString shuffle1 = list.takeFirst();

    std::random_shuffle(list.begin()+11, list.begin()+20);
    list.takeFirst();
    QString shuffle2 = list.takeFirst();

    std::random_shuffle(list.begin()+21, list.end());
    list.takeFirst();
    QString shuffle3 = list.takeFirst();enter code here
```

but it doesn't work. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you take two items off while ignoring the first, but I think the main problem is that you are trying to shuffle with the logic that the items are intact, whereas you actually remove items when calling `list.takeFirst()` between the shuffling calls. Therefore, the shuffling will not anymore work on the original as you may seem to expect.

Here is some example code that fixes this issue:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // You better generate this test data for 30 items...
    QStringList stringList{"a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6"};
    static const int sliceSize = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i+=sliceSize) {
        std::random_shuffle(stringList.begin() + i, stringList.begin() + (i+sliceSize-1));
        qDebug() << stringList.mid(i, sliceSize);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
("a1", "b2")
("c3", "d4")
("e5", "f6")
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i was not complete clear in my question. First i used .takeFirst because i dont want repeat values in the shuffles. Second, the range is not fixed (the first 10, then the next 8, then next 7 ( i know i wrote ranges of ten (my bad)). and after all that i'll do a last shuffle with all the remain elements of the list. And cant be repeated. how i do this? thks

Comment: @Rafaelpsmed: Please give the expected inputs and outputs. It will hopefully be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve. It sounds a bit incomprehensive to me at this point.

Comment: ok its like this: i have a list of 60 items. the final output will be 6 items of that 60 initial items. first i need to shuffle the first 10 itens and pick one, then shuffle the next 9 itens and pick one, then the next 8 items and pick one. 3 items so far. next i shuffle the entire list and pick 3 more items. makes a total of 6 items. and items can not be repeated

Comment: @Rafaelpsmed: interesting algorithm, but what exactly is this for? What happens when the string exists in the result list when you are trying to pick, you are trying to pick the next one? Also, what exactly is not working? Still, the `list.takeFirst();` calls do not seem to make sense based on your updated problem description.

Comment: this is a lottery app for my father (he belives that some numbers are better than others) thats why i want to shuffle parts of the list (because are his "magic numbers") and then the whole list like i said. if list.takeFirst does not make sense, what should i use to put the result of each the shuffle in a string to display to the user?

Comment: what is not working is this: the first shuffle (between the first ten items of the list) works fine. the second shuffle and the third shuffle (between the 11th and the 19th item and between the 20th and the 28th items) doesn work (what shows is another shuffle of the first ten items).

Comment: Yes i did. I cant share now because im not at home. When i come back i will share the answer